# Dynamically generating radio button name?

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

I am having a foreach loop under that i am having a radio buttons as mentioned below .

My code below :

```
@section Scripts {

  <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ViewModel/LeadQualification.js")"></script>
}


    <div style="width: 1100px; height: 700px;" class="container">
        <div style="width: 1100px; height: 110px; background-color: burlywood">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 400px; height: 110px; background-color: burlywood;" align="left">
                        <h3>Qualification Factor</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 400px; height: 110px; background-color: burlywood" align="center">
                        <h3>Score</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 400px; height: 110px; background-color: burlywood" align="center">
                        <h3>Comment</h3>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 1100px; height: 580px; border: 1px solid; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: scroll;" >       
                          <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" align="center"></td>
                                    <td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <h4>Negative</h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <h4>Neutral</h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <h4>Positive</h4>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </table>
            <table>              
                <tbody data-bind="foreach: leadqualificlist">                     
                    <tr>

                        <td style="width: 250px; height: 130px;"> 

                          <h4 data-bind="text: $data.LeadQualifition"></h4>                       
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 580px; height: 80px;">

                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">

                                        <h4 data-bind="text: $data.Negativescore" 0-1-2-3>
                                            <br />
                                            </h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <h4 data-bind="text: $data.Neutralscore" 4-5-6>
                                            <br />
                                            </h4>
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                        <h4 data-bind="text: $data.Positivescore" 7-8-9>
                                            <br />

                                            </h4>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>


                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">


                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px;  height: 20px;" name="grp"  value="0" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"  name="grp"  value="1" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk"  />
                                       <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"  name="grp" value="2"  data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" name="grp"   value="3" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                       <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" name="grp"  value="4" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
                                      <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"  name="grp" value="5" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
                                        <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"  name="grp"  value="6" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />

                                    </td>
                                    <td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                                       <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" name="grp"  value="7" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
                                       <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" name="grp"  value="8" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
                                       <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" name="grp" value="9" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />

                                    </td>

                                </tr>


                            </table>
                        </td>
                       <td>
                            <textarea style="width: 300px; height: 110px;" data-bind="value: $data.Commenttext">Text Box
                            </textarea>

                        </td>
                    </tr>                                 
                </tbody>




            </table>

            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td align="center">

                         @*<button data-bind="click :$root.create"  style="background-color:burlywood">Save</button>*@
                        <input type="submit" title="Save" value="Submit" data-bind="click:$root.create" style="background-color: burlywood" />
                        <input type="submit" title="Save" value="Next Stage" style="background-color: burlywood" />
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

iSSUE here is i want to have a radio buttons grouping based on row . if i have a static name i.e name="grp" when i selet other radio button the other selection getting effected .

So i want to assign a dynamic name ? is there any better alternative which works for me in this case .

Your efforts are appreciated 
Regards

Comment: What you mean by other selection getting effected ?

Comment: Use checkbox for multiple selections

Comment: in my above code there is a foreach loop which will run 10 times . As per my code i will get 10 tr's each TR have some set of radio buttons which should be grouped . Problem i am facing is simple as i am having name to radio buttons of all my TR'S same when i select something other getting effected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try like following it will work.

```
data-bind='attr: { name: "grp" + $data.Negativescore}'
```

Kindly try the following:

```
<input type="radio" style="width: 20px;  height: 20px;"  value="0" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk, attr: { name: "grp" + $data.Negativescore}" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It is the reply to the user comment: added my entire html code . You can find data-bind="text: $data.Negativescore" under my foreach loop every time this loop runs the given data-bind will dynamic rather static .. I just need the above databind code to bind with my name in radio buttons in my TR . i tried like name="grp"+$data.Negativescore //not working any ideas

Comment: Their can not be two databinds

Comment: You can add it in single data-bind. i have updated it kindly check.

Comment: Perfect solution thanks for your help u saved me lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want radion buttons under one `td` should belong to same group.
To achieve it you can assign `id` to `td`s and append it to radio button names. So that all radio under one `td` will belong to same group and wont affect each others selection.
[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6raK5/1/)

Comment: yes just checked fiddle . thats what i need but you given name static and i need that dynamic

Comment: @user3483538 Add your script which dynamically populates the radios.

Comment: well scripts will be very big to post . to make to simple i will get a list of data in foreach loop . list[0] contains 4 listitems likely i may have list[n] . can i use any one value from list[0] to make my TR name dynamic .

Comment: well but i dont know how to bind in my case . any suggestions ?

Comment: added my entire html code . You can find **data-bind="text: $data.Negativescore"** under my foreach loop every time this loop runs the given data-bind will dynamic rather static .. 
I just need the above databind code to bind with my name in radio buttons in my TR . i tried like name="grp"+$data.Negativescore //not working any ideas

Comment: can check my answer for this type of binding.

Answer (score 0):

dynamic append radio button?

used jquery...

1. get radio button

   ```
    var rbtn = $(':radio[name=" your radio btn name here "]:checked').val();
   ```
2. add radio button

   ```
   $('# your div id here').append('<input type="radio" style=.....>' button!! '</input>' );
   ```
3. dynamically data -> AJAX used

   ```
   $.ajax({
           type : "POST",
           url : "your data url here!!",
           dataType : "json",
           success : function(obj) {
           // your cod here  
           },

           error: function() {
           // your code hear
           }

   }
   ```
4. add radio btn by JSON Object

   ```
   success : function(obj) {
       $('# your div id here').append('<input type="radio" style=.....>'+obj.(your code here)+'</input>');
   }
   ```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to answer? I cant see anything like Ajax, JSON in question

Answer (score 0):

This line should be in outside of table tage

```
 <%String day="grp" %>
```

This line can be after tbody tag

```
 <%
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)

    %>
```

In your td tage use this    `<td id=day<%=i> >`

so your td Id will be grp0, grp1,grp2 and so on.

Comment: hie , i need a same name to entire 9 radio buttons in TR .. but each tr should have different .

Comment: <% for(int j=0;i<3;j++)%> and give tr id name <tr name=day<%=j>

Comment: dude i have foreach loop via knockout . i guess i cant use the above thing you given .My loop code looks like ** data-bind="foreach: leadqualificlist" ** . with this i have to make name dynamic .

Answer (score 0):

you can give the value and name as same value..

> name="0" value="0"

```
<td style="width: 210px; height: 50px;" align="center">
                <input type="radio" style="width: 20px;  height: 20px;" name="0" value="0" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
                <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" name="1" value="1" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
                <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" name="2" value="2" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
                <input type="radio" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" name="3" value="3" data-bind="checked:Scoreschk" />
            </td>
```

Comment: Then all radio buttons will belong to different group and you can select every radio button.

Comment: i am looking for something different mate : rolind

Comment: then you can use some server side scripts like php, jsp. then you will get exact what you want. thank you